# Python - Sum absolute value from file

Tags: python, numpy, sum

How calculate sum absolute value from text file in Python ?

```
time = np.loadtxt("data.svc",delimiter=' ',skiprows=1, usecols=(2),unpack=True) 

for i in range(len(time)): 
sumTime = sum(abs(time[i]-time[i+1]))
```

I need: `(|time[0]-time[1]|)+(|time[1]-time[2]|)+(|time[2]-time[3]|)....`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: .svc means csv?

Comment: You could try: `np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(time)))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use NumPy functions to get the desired result:

```
np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(time)))
```

This works according to your desired formula even though `np.diff` calculates the difference `time[i+1] - time[i]` (instead of `time[i] - time[i+1]`) because you're using the absolute value.

Because this uses NumPy functions on a NumPy array it's probably much faster than any Python comprehension and/or functions.

Answer (score 1):

You want list generator:

```
li = [abs(time[i-1] - t) for i, t in enumerate(time) if i > 0]
sum(li)
```

make list of difference between current and previous element starting with second element (by index 1).

Comment: Do you think `t` can be indexed? This does not work, nor does a list answer OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @GrailFinder, but I try: np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(time))) and It works right.

Comment: You don't need the list comprehension, you could directly feed it as generator to the `sum`: `sum(abs(time[i-1] - t) for i, t in enumerate(time) if i > 0)`.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions give the same result :)